# ¿Navegar en una misma página con Vue sin scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Estoy haciendo una página con Vue, y necesito navegar en la misma página sin hacer scroll, se que vanilla se hace así:

```
<a href='#menu'>Menú</a>

<h2 id='menu'>Menú</h2>
```

pero con Vue no puedo acceder a los id de los demás componentes, igual estoy haciendo esa técnica desde un mismo componente y tampoco funciona.

Gracias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En este caso uso un boton pero podrias usar un link o cualquier otra cosa para hacer el scroll.

1. colocar el id correspondiente a cada elemento seguido de botones o links para cada uno.

```
<button @click="scrollInto('element1')">Ir Elemento1</button>
...
...

<div id="element1"></div
<div id="element2"></div
<div id="element3"></div
```

2. Esta funcion tomara el id del elemento, con esto buscara el DOM virtual de este elemento y usando la funcion `scrollIntoView` la pagina se movera hasta ese elemento, el `behavior: 'smooth'` es para que el movimiento sea suave.

```
scrollInto(elementId: string) {
    const section = this.$el.querySelector(`#${elementId}`);
    section!.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
}
```

[Ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/Sebastian1830/xkof2w6h/43/)

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {},
  methods: {
    scrollInto(elementId) {
      const section = document.querySelector(`#${elementId}`);
      section.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth'
      });
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

#element1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#element2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#element3 {
  background-color: green;
}

div {
  color: white;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="scrollInto('element1')">Elemento 1</button>
  <button @click="scrollInto('element2')">Elemento 2</button>
  <button @click="scrollInto('element3')">Elemento 3</button>
  <div id="element1">Hola</div>
  <div id="element2">Mundo</div>
  <div id="element3">Scroll</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Una solución con puro CSS, sin usar Javascript, es usar la propiedad CSS [`scroll-behavior`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior) con el valor `smooth` en el elemento contenedor (El que provoca el scroll), en el ejemplo lo he añadido al elemento `html`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
```

```css
section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: Impact;
  background-color: #ffbb00;
}


#section-2 {
  background-color: #00bbff;
}

.button-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 6px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="button-container">
    <button v-for="i in 3" :key="i">
      <a :href="`#section-${i}`">Section {{i}}</a>
    </button>
  </div>
  
  <section v-for="i in 3" :key="i" :id="`section-${i}`">Section {{i}}</section>
</div>
```